# Which growth model is better?

Tags: game-theory

I have a game I am playing that I can spend units (explanation would be complicated) to earn units faster. My growth rate depends on the number of units spent. At the moment I am growing at a rate of 1/100,000 units per second. There are several increase options:

1. Spend 1 unit to gain about 1/1,000,000 increase in growth rate
2. spend 4 units to gain about 5/1,000,000 increase in growth rate
3. Spend 30 units to gain about 50/1,000,000 increase in growth rate
4. Spend 50 units to gain 100/1,000,000 increase in growth rate

As it takes just over 1 day to gain 1 unit, is it faster to spend 1 unit every time I can or to save for 4(ish) days and buy the larger? Or even save for 50+ days?
Does spending early cause a faster increase then spending less?

Comment: The tag `evolutionary game theory` doesn't apply here.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know what tag to use. It is game theory isn't it?

Comment: You say that it takes a one day to earn one unit at a rate of $1/1,000,000$ unit per second, but there are only $86,400$ seconds in a day.  Something is wrong.

Comment: It takes JUST OVER 1 day i said. 86400/100000 units per day.

Comment: Up above you said the rate is $1/1,000,,00$ and now you say it's $1/100,000$.  DON"T SHOUT!

Comment: Apologies, did not mean to shout, was using as emphasis